# TensorFlow Tutorial on Sequence-to-Sequence Models: Running translate.py return CRC check failure

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run tutorial for sequence-to-sequence model, but running the following command

```
bazel run -c opt <...>/models/rnn/translate/translate.py --data_dir [your_data_directory]
```

ends with the following error

```
    for line in gz_file:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 462, in readline
    c = self.read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 268, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 315, in _read
    self._read_eof()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 354, in _read_eof
    hex(self.crc)))
IOError: CRC check failed 0xb94c52ed != 0xc6088f89L
ERROR: Non-zero return code '1' from command: Process exited with status 1.
```

Did I do something wrong, or is there (another) error in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove files in dir /tmp:

- training-giga-fren.tar
- giga-fren.release2.en.gz
- giga-fren.release2.fr.gz

And then rerun 
bazel run -c opt <...>/models/rnn/translate/translate.py --data_dir [your_data_directory]